# Sails EJS-view after html-pdf usage does not render image

Tags: javascript, image, pdf, sails.js, ejs

I need to be able to render html views (nothing new there) and to provide the same views as PDF file to the final user.

The first case works perfectly on my side : I managed to render a simple html5 document aswell as an image two times (the base64 version + the standard way).

Unfortunately, when I try to convert it to a PDF file thanks to `html5-to-pdf` or `html-pdf`, the non-base64 version of the `<img>` tag does not work and is signaled as a missing resource within the PDF File.

The code I'm using is the following :

Controller :

```
//res is the response parameter provided to the controller

var pdf = require('html-pdf');

var variables = {

};

ejs.renderFile('./views/samplepdf.ejs', variables, function(err, result) {
  // render on success
  if (result) {
    html = result;

    pdf.create(html).toStream(function(err, stream){
      res.contentType("application/pdf");
      stream.pipe(res);
    });

  }
  // render or error
  else {
    res.end('An error occurred');
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

View :

```
<h2>Image</h2>
<img class="smaller" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/validbase64ButIHadToSaveBecauseCharactersLimitExceeded" alt="Sample image" />
<img class="smaller" src="images/ymca.jpg" alt="Sample image #2" />
```

I've carefully read the Sails specification about Grunt tasks and assets management, therefore the given `images/ymca.jpg` does exist and can be access from the browser. I still do not know why does the PDF does not render it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all you have to do is use full path of image while render on pdf
controller

```
var variables = {
  path: sails.config.appPath + 'assets/images/ymca.jpg'
};
```

view

```
<img class="smaller" src="<%= path %>" alt="Sample image #2" />
```

while render on pdf using html-pdf, it does not work with absolute path.

Comment: Sorry for being late to reply but your answer solved my problem :) Thanks a lot ! Had to adapt it  a bit because of my dev environment (Windows) so I prefixed the path with the ''file'' protocol and it works fine ! Thank you again, wish you a happy new year

Comment: happy new year, have a g8 year.